# Regular expression to match pattern and any number.

Tags: regex, url-rewriting

I have a URL pattern which can be

```
my-domain.com/my-path/prod234728749.html
```

I want to create a rule to match any URL combination with:

```
"/my-path/prod" + anycombination-of-number + ".html"
```

The combination can be a combination of different numbers of unknown length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\d+`  or `[0-9]+` for combination. The complete would be `/my-path/prod[0-9]+\\.html` or `/my-path/prod\d+\\.html`